# Python list(set()) inside a loop is splitting element by letter

Tags: python, list

In a loop I'm trying to make an list.

```
sedol_list = []
for d in self.holdings_history.keys():
        for i in np.arange(0,len(self.holdings_history[d]),1) :
            sedol_list = list(set(self.holdings_history[d][i].sedol))
```

This used to work, each sedol was adding to the list.

Today it is not working but rather splitting each "sedol" by letter and adding each letter to the sedol_list.

It then moves to the next "sedol" splits it by letter and then overwrites the sedol_list.

I've made no changes to my packages, running on windows (Visual Studio Code) and linux environments with the same issue...

Prelim test with Spyder looked ok

Comment: Please provide a **[mcve]**. I can't debug your code since I am unable to run it in its current form.

Comment: if `sedol` is a string, it makes sense that the `set` operator will split the string by letters

Comment: working on that now

Comment: Checkout my solution, i did this for you and cleaned the code a little

Comment: an example of what @mckuok said: `list(set('abcdefabc'))` gives `['a', 'f', 'e', 'd', 'b', 'c']`

Comment: I'm amazed it work previously then (maybe it didn't and I hadn't noticed it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sedol_list = set()
for d in self.holdings_history.keys():
        for i in np.arange(0,len(self.holdings_history[d]),1) :
            sedol_list.add(self.holdings_history[d][i].sedol))
```

You basically used the set method on a string (which is syntactically right because strings are arrays in python and other languages) so you just get a bunch of non redundant characters from a string. Hopefully this fixed your problem!

Comment: Amazing this absolutely works but throws an arrow down the chain TypeError: 'set' object has no attribute '__getitem__' which i'll work on

Comment: You could just convert the set back to a list afterwards. E.g.: sedol_list = list(sedol_list)